# Google Cloud API PHP Client Authentication using Service Account

Tags: php, xampp, google-cloud-platform, google-api-php-client, google-authentication

I'm working with a project using PHP and need to implement Google Cloud APIs using PHP Client library, but the authentication does not seem to be working for me.
I have created a service account and granted the project owner permissions and I don't want to make authentication by using the GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CREDENTIALS environment variable, I want to use service account authentication.

Here's what I have tried:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Core\ServiceBuilder;
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

// Authentication with Google Cloud Platform
$client = new ServiceBuilder([
    'keyFilePath' => 'api-project-374381085870-eaf930d9ffd7.json'
]);
$client = new StorageClient();
$bucket = $client->bucket('storage_client');

// Upload a file to the bucket.
$bucket->upload(
    fopen('file.txt', 'r')
);
```

But it returns an error as:

> Warning: file_get_contents(/Users/abdul/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/storage/vendor/google/auth/src/CredentialsLoader.php on line 102
>
> Warning:
> file_get_contents(/Users/abdul/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json):
> failed to open stream: Permission denied in
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/storage/vendor/google/auth/src/CredentialsLoader.php
> on line 102
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
> 'Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException' with message '{
> "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "authError",
> "message": "Invalid Credentials", "locationType": "header",
> "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Invalid
> Credentials" } } ' in
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/storage/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php:263
> Stack trace: #0
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/storage/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php(168):
> Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->convertToGoogleException(Object(GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException))
>
> ## 1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/storage/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/Upload/MultipartUploader.php(65):
>
> Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->send(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request),
> Array) #2
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/storage/vendor/google/cloud-storage/src/Bucket.php(283):
> Google\Cloud\Core\Upload\MultipartUploader->upload() #3
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppf in
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/storage/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php
> on line 263

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Provide your `keyFilePath` to the class which you are actually using. The `ServiceBuilder` instantiation is unnecessary here. `new StorageClient(['keyFilePath' => '...']);`

Comment: Hi @jdp, thanks, it's working... you can post an answer if you want.

Comment: great! glad it worked. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyfile configuration must be provided to the client which is being called. The ServiceBuilder is often convenient because it allows you to create a single instance with your configuration, and that configuration is passed to each new client.

In your example, you've created a ServiceBuilder instance with a keyfile, but you're not using that instance to call Storage.

Two options:

```
use Google\Cloud\Core\ServiceBuilder;

$cloud = new ServiceBuilder([
    'keyFilePath' => 'my-keyfile.json'
]);

$storage = $cloud->storage();
```

or

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$storage = new StorageClient([
    'keyFilePath' => 'my-keyfile.json'
]);
```

In both examples, `$storage` should be authenticated and ready to use!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is being generated due to the way you are creating the StorageClient object and specifying the the private key file parameter.

You can find the following example to [Pass the path to the service account key in code](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually) on Google Cloud Platform site that is a very useful reference for your issue:

```
namespace Google\Cloud\Samples\Auth;

// Imports the Google Cloud Storage client library.
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

function auth_cloud_explicit($projectId, $serviceAccountPath)
{
    # Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key
    # file.
    $config = [
        'keyFilePath' => $serviceAccountPath,
        'projectId' => $projectId,
    ];
    $storage = new StorageClient($config);

    # Make an authenticated API request (listing storage buckets)
    foreach ($storage->buckets() as $bucket) {
        printf('Bucket: %s' . PHP_EOL, $bucket->name());
    }
}
```